# Ansible: how to store the result of a json_query?

Tags: json, filter, ansible

In the Ansible documentation on [filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter), the following example is shown, which executes a JSON query on a data structure, selecting certain fields `name` and `port`:

```
- name: "Display all server ports and names from cluster1"
  debug: var=item
  with_items: "{{domain_definition|json_query(server_query)}}"
  vars:
    server_query: "domain.server[?cluster=='cluster2'].{name: name, port: port}"
```

I managed to use this logic to parse the JSON response of a REST service, but I would like to not only print out the result, but reuse it several times again during my playbook.

How is it possible to persist the above variable `var` for later use?

Comment: You always do this with `set_fact`. I'm not sure what this question is about. There is a method to use `set_fact` in a loop. And it's not a `var` variable, it's an argument called `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `debug` call with `set_fact`. For example:

```
- name: "Display all server ports and names from cluster1"
  set_fact:
    'name_{{ item.name }}': '{{ item.port }}'
  with_items: "{{domain_definition|json_query(server_query)}}"
  vars:
    server_query: "domain.server[?cluster=='cluster2'].{name: name, port: port}"
```

This will generate two persistent facts (based on docs data): `name_server21` with value `9080` and `name_server22` = `9090`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried using `set_fact`, but apparently not the correct way... With your hint I could achieve what I want :)