# Ansible json_query - struggling with syntax

Tags: ansible, json-query

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048032/ansible-how-to-store-the-result-of-a-json-query) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541438/extracting-a-variable-from-json-output-then-debug-and-register-the-outout-with-a) as well as the relevant [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter).

I still can't work out what the correct syntax to use is.  I am trying the following:

```
# Find all of the load-balancers reference
- name: Gather facts about all load-balancers
  elb_application_lb_facts:
  register: load_balancers

# Get the load-balancer we want
- name: Find the correct load-balancer
  set_fact:
    load_balancer_dns: "{{ load_balancer_dns }}"
    elb_zone_id: "{{ elb_zone_id }}"
  with_items: "{{ load_balancers | json_query(lb_query) }}"
  vars:
    lb_query: "load_balancers[?load_balancer_name=='{{load_balancer_name}}'].{load_balancer_dns: dns_name, elb_zone_id: canonical_hosted_zone_id}"
```

This always results in the error (in the second task):  `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'load_balancer_dns' is undefined`.

The JSON output from the `elb_application_lb_facts` does include the `dns_name` and `canonical_hosted_zone_id` keys and they are on the same level as `load_balancer_name` (not nested somewhere).

Please could somebody help me with the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include "item" when you set the fact, because you're looping "with_items":

```
# Get the load-balancer we want
- name: Find the correct load-balancer
  set_fact:
    load_balancer_dns: "{{ item.load_balancer_dns }}"
    elb_zone_id: "{{ item.elb_zone_id }}"
  with_items: "{{ load_balancers | json_query(lb_query) }}"
  vars:
    lb_query: "load_balancers[?load_balancer_name=='simple-application-load-balancer'].{load_balancer_dns: dns_name, elb_zone_id: canonical_hosted_zone_id}"
```

Documented here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items